# How to do partial redeployment in SAP Cloud Foundry using blue-green mode?

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk, sap-cloud-foundry

We are using mta to structure our application consisting of multiple micro-services.
The mtar file is deployed to SAP Cloud Foundry in blue-green mode using the SAP Cloud SDK pipeline (**Piper Project** -> **cloudFoundryDeploy** step).

We are running into the below issue while trying partial deployment with the blue-green strategy.

**Issue:** If MTA with same ID is redeployed, pipeline creates new MTA color (Blue to Green and vice-versa) and all applications with the old color are deleted. This approach creates issue during partial deployments.

For instance - using blue-green deployment approach, assume that we have deployed 10 micro-services to SAP CF space.
After bug fixes, we want to do partial redeployment for only a couple of micro-services.

In this case, if we use the same MTA ID and include only the two micro-services in mta.yaml, pipeline deletes the other 8 micro-services which are already deployed to SAP CF.

We tried updating the MTA version but it doesn't make any difference.

As a result of this issue, we unnecessarily need to redeploy all the 10 micro-services again although fix was done for only a couple of micro-services.

On the flip side, if we use a different MTA ID for redeploying the two micro-services, pipeline treats those as initial deployment and triggers an action which is same as the standard deployment type. This results in downtime and defies the purpose of blue-green deployment approach.

Appreciate if someone can help us here to resolve this issue of partial deployment using blue-green strategy and guide us on the best practices to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is currently possible, and the right place to build this would probably be [multiapps-cli-plugin](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/multiapps-cli-plugin). I think it would be best if you opened an issue in that repo.

On another note: With that requirement of "partial deployments" I'm not sure if MTA is the best choice. Is there a reason why you need MTA? If you had one maven project per microservice, with one pipeline each this would be closer to the general concept of microservices where each unit can be deployed independently.

Hope this helps

Florian